# How to stop (neo)vim from yanking text on pasting over selection?

Tags: neovim, cut-copy-paste

I want to make Neovim stop yanking the text I paste over into my register (mapped to system clipboard with `vim.opt.clipboard = 'unnamedplus'`), eg

If I have the text:

```
asdfghjkl
asdfghjkl
asdfghjkl
```

and I v over 'sdfgh', hit y, then go to the second line and v over 'as' and hit paste it will copy 'as' to my clipboard, I want it to keep 'sdfgh' instead

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37251/23502) could help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `P` instead of `p` in visual mode.  This will preserve the register.

To make this default, you can use a map such as

```
xnoremap p P
```

Comment: Will this not also make regular p behave like P (eg alter paste position etc ?)

Comment: @Madoka `xnoremap` only affects Visual modes.

Comment: @d-ben-knoble Ah, okay Thank You !

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lua, update your keymaps.lua file to include:

```lua
-- mode
--  "n" - normal mode
--  "i" - insert mode
--  "x" - visual mode
--  "v" - visual and select mode

local function map(m, k, v)
    vim.keymap.set(m, k, v, { silent = true })
end

map("x", "p", "P")
```

This remaps `p`, which yanks text on paste with `P`, which doesn't yank text on paste.

Notes:

- Use `x` not `v` [Should I use xmap or vmap in my mappings?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11852/should-i-use-xmap-or-vmap-in-my-mappings)
- No need for `noremap = true` as `remap` works here and it is already set to `false` [link](https://matrix.to/#/!cylwlNXSwagQmZSkzs:matrix.org/$_vYEv-JVZtBCnP7KUCN5EcH1z_flTyshNo88tYFi8mI)

Comment: oh, good idea! i ended up setting a remap for pgvy as p instead so it yanks back whatever the selected text before pasting was but this is a good idea too!

Comment: this looks nice, but does not work for me. This worked https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25259/clipboard-is-reset-after-first-paste-in-visual-mode/25260#25260